# Can't figure out this binding expression

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I've inherited a large Flex 4 project which contains (imo) some "unique and exuberant" forms and uses of binding and event messaging.

After staring at the binding expression below (as defined in the .mxml), I see that it is apparently a NOT plus Logical AND (i.e. ! showShell && blanked). The vars it refers to are shown at bottom.

```
  visible="{!showShell &amp;&amp; blanked}"
```

Can anyone confirm that this is what it is doing?

---

```
[Bindable]
 public var showShell:Boolean = true;

[Bindable]
public var blanked:Boolean = true;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right.

```
visible="{!showShell &amp;&amp; blanked}"
```

In MXML Binding-Expressions you have to use "&amp;" for the &-operator. It also is necessary for all other operators which have a special meaning in xml. Thus you must also replace < (&lt;) , > (&gt;), " (&quot;) and ' (&apos;).